# The best way in C# to wrap operations in context/scope

Tags: c#, .net

I want to implement some some kind of shared disposable resource - The Scope or a Context - that should be the same for several operations that are wrapped inside that scope. For ex:

```
using(var ctx = Context.Create())
{
    var obj = ReadSmth();
    ChangeObject(obj);
    SomeActionWithReadWriteInside();
    Write(obj);
}
```

Read, Change, Write should use exactly the same instance of context object inside it (WITHOUT passing it directly, like we're using a TransactionScope). There also could be the situation when inside ChangeObject method the other read\write operations occurred, they also should be included in this context. BUT another using(ctx) block on another thread shouldn't interfere with that context.

UPD1: I understand the possible issues with introducing the super-global object, problems with ASP.NET threads switching and async/await part-switching and testing problems. But in some cases inside your solution with certain restriction this approach has a right to exist. I just want to ask for the structure of this pattern.

What is the best way to implement such kind of behavior in .NET/C#?

UPD2: seems like there have been several existing solutions with its own problems, so it can't be used as industry standard, but the good way to start with:

- https://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/the-ambient-context-design-pattern-in-net/
- https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/nice-free-and-reusable-net-ambient-context-pattern-implementation/

Comment: use thread local storage?

Comment: I wanna make code more clean without passing the context inside all the methods and methods of methods and so on, cause there could be lots of nesting methods inside.

Comment: Daniel A. White: may be, but is it the best solution for all the situations in multithreaded environment?

Comment: "more clean" is a case of opinion. I'd say that the code is cleaner if it tells you exactly what it expects. In this case there is no indication that the method requires a context of any kind which means that you now have to "remember" to do things correctly. Cleaner in my mind would be that the code *actually* requires you to do things correctly.

Comment: yes, I agree. The key subject is the size of the source code - my example is just an abstraction. imagine that you have a lot of legacy code written by someone with a lot of nesting levels that is reading\writing something and there is a strong need in implementing transactional support. That's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something C# supports naurally so if you want to do it you'll have to roll your own solution. Here's an approach but I'd not want to use it in production -- passing a variable's not so hard that the complexity is worth it. Also, the code is not 'clean' in that what you have to do is introduce a big stinking global (your 'current context') and now you've written code which is much harder to test and isolate.

However, it's interesting to think about, so here's an approach...

First, create a ThreadStatic variable containing a stack of every context;

```
public static class Contexts
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public Stack<Context> contexts;

    public Context CurrentContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (contexts == null || contexts.Count == 0) { return null; }
            return contexts.Peek();
        }
    }

    public void ContextCreated(Context obj)
    {
        if (contexts == null) { contexts = new Stack<Context>(); }
        contexts.Push(obj);
    }

    public void ContextDisposed()
    {
        if (contexts == null) { contexts = new Stack<Context>(); }
        contexts.Pop();
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you create a new context, add it to the stack, and on dispose, pop it off the stack;

```
public class Context: IDisposable
{
    public Context
    {
        Contexts.ContextCreated(this);
    }

    public void Dispose
    {
        Contexts.ContextDisposed(this);
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you just refer to

```
 Contexts.CurrentContext
```

This is fraught with errors, though. For example, in multithreaded code, or code that uses async/await, this fails horribly. And all we're doing is maintaining something equivalent to the call stack, and there's a really easy, well-supported way you get something onto the call stack, and that's method parameters.

Comment: thank you, Steve! That's the good approach to start with. but I think I won't use ThreadStatic to be able to control all the lifecycle of that and use some kind of Dictionary to store the contexts.

Comment: The thread static/stack pattern mirrors what happens with function calls. Interested to know what a dictionary gives you?

Comment: ThreadStatic makes no sence in ASP.NET environment and with ThreadPool, too, so I wanna make different techniques for different platforms. I thought both Dictionary and Stack is an overhead - so I can just create an Object with link to itself to store the inner scope. Also it looks like I found an implementation that is suitable with several improvements (get rid of dictionary and use HttpContext.Current.Items for ASP.NET implementaion instead of ThreadStatic) - https://github.com/minimod/minimods/blob/master/MiniMods/ThreadVariable/ThreadVariable.cs

Comment: I guess you can work through the issues one at a time, but I've had a couple of goes at this and you constantly find issues (for example, when someone uses async/await and the thread switches half-way through the method, for example?) Plus all your code is now pinned to whatever global, dictionary-like structure you use to store variables, so things are hard to test. Worth noting that Common Lisp called these 'Dynamic Variables' so there's a precendent, but generally languages prefer lexical scoping.

Comment: thank you Steve once more. I understand all the drawbacks of that approach. Do you think TransactionScope in .NET is some kind of evil? What can you offer instead?

Comment: @IvanYuriev I believe `ThreadStatic` makes more sense than you think in those environment. You should look at the `ExecutionContext` class, which I believe is used to store the `ThreadStatic` members (its badly named).

Comment: @SteveCooper "This isn't something C# supports naurally" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aron - looks interesting. Can you use this to handle, say, a thread switch that occurs when you use `await` and the thread changes? Had terrible trouble with this when writing a async message processing service so I've shied away from being clever about these kinds of things.

Comment: @SteveCooper this is used internally in Task.Run.

Comment: @IvanYuriev "what can you offer instead?" Just function calls instead of global variables. Absolutely guaranteed to work, very familiar to other devs, not considered an anti-pattern. On TransactionScope: not really a problem because a method not in a transaction isn't written differently from one inside a transaction, really. With your dynamic variables, a function will fail, or not, based on whether it's called somewhere with a `using` block around it. That's fragile. (I'm only going on about it because I've been down this path and you just end up rolling it back because it's flakey)